Would you like to have children (for) one day?
This is from a FB group 'PunHub':
-- Would you like to have children one day?
-- Ok, but no longer than that.
I am wondering if this pun actually works as it seems to me that 'for' is mandatory before 'one' if the question is to mean 'for the duration of'.

The 'for' is not 'mandatory'. I had my mother-in-law to stay one week. It seemed like a year

Like many puns, it doesn't have to work perfectly, only well enough to take the expected meaning and redirect it to another. Yes, more words would usually needed to be idiomatic when talking about a temporary stay (E.g. Michael avoided "for," but added "to stay"). I suppose someone whose child died one day after being born might actually say "We had him only one day."

It implies for. That's the joke.

@AndyBonner So the pun makes use of the borderline idiomaticity, doesn't it? Would this sentence sound both idiomatic and ambiguous: 'I didn't know I would have terrible stomachaches one day'?

Well, you're still right, it would be more idiomatic to say "I had a stomachache for one day" than to omit the for. Perhaps it could be more successful using a "have to" construction rather than "have": "You know you'll have to act like an adult one day, don't you?!" "Okay. One day. And the day after, it's right back to fun and games."

@AndyBonner Thanks. Pragmatically speaking, it seems there are not many contexts that would allow for some ambiguity in case of 'one day'.

This comes up in many plays on words. E.g. Groucho Marx's famous "I shot an elephant in my pajamas. How he got into my pajamas I'll never know." There wouldn't be a joke if he said "while I was wearing pajamas".
